# Powershell: How to press a button on a web page if you don't know the button ID

Tags: html, dom, button, powershell, web

I'm trying to fill in my username and password on a certain web page and then the press the "sign-in" button, all automatically via Powershell.

The problem is that I cannot find the ID of the sign-in button in the html source code.

I have tried to use the command:

```
$link = $ie.Document.getElementsByTagName('A') | where-object {$_.innerText -match 'sign in'}
```

but this didn't worked either.

Any thoughts which PS command to use if I want to press the 'sign in' button?

The HTML code is as follows:

```
<div class="login">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="subsection-1">Sign in or create a <a id="ctl00_HeaderUserControl_LoginUserControl_hypNewAccount" href="/authentication/registerprovider.aspx?">new account</a></div>
        <div class="subsection-2">
            <span class="navy bold">What is your email address?</span>
            <div class="indent">
                <span class="bold">Email:</span>
                <input id="loginEmail" class="text-box" type="text" maxlength="100" tabindex="1" />
                <img class="ajax-loader" src="/content/images/research/global/transparent.gif" alt="" />
            </div>
            <div class="invalid-email"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="subsection-3">
            <span class="navy bold">Do you know your password?</span>
            <div>
                <input id="passwordNotKnown" name="passwordSwitch" type="radio" checked="checked" />
                <label for="noPassword">No, I don't know my password or I'm new .</label>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input id="passwordKnown" name="passwordSwitch" type="radio" />
                <label for="noPassword">Yes, my password is:</label>
                <input id="loginPassword" class="text-box" type="password" maxlength="50" tabindex="2" />
            </div>
            <div class="invalid-password"></div>
            <div class="error"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="subsection-4">
            <button type="button" class="login-button greenButton" tabindex="4">Sign in</button>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="cancel-link">Cancel</a>
            <input id="stayLoggedIn" type="checkbox" tabindex="3" />
            <label for="stayLoggedIn">Stay signed in</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="reset-password">
        <div class="subsection-1">Would you like to reset your password?</div>
        <div class="subsection-2">Choosing <span class="bold">yes</span> will reset your password and email a temporary password to: <span class="repeat-email"></span></div>
        <div class="subsection-3">
            <div class="center">
                <button class="reset-password-button" type="button">Yes</button>
                <button class="do-not-reset-password-button" type="button">No</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The sign in button isn't an `A` Tag, it's a button: `<button type="button" class="login-button greenButton" tabindex="4">Sign in</button>`

Comment: Are you attempting to bypass the login page of a OpenID or OAuth provider? If you are, and you are discovered by API provider that you are using, you will likely have your API key revoked.

Answer (score 3):

I came here looking for a similar answer and figured out how to get this done.  Posting here for any future searchers.  As noted by Szymon, `getElementsByClassName` returns an array, and you will need to select the item you need before the click. In my case the classname was `button` and I was able to click it using the following:

```
$submitButton = $doc.documentElement.getElementsByClassName('button') | Select-Object -First 1
$submitButton.click()
```

This works for me because there is only the one item with the classname button, so your results my vary if you have more than one with the same name.  Just change what you grab using select-object if need be.

Answer (score 2):

As @Jamie-Taylor mentioned the login button is in fact a button.

You can access it not only by the id but also by the class name using `document.documentElement.getElementsByClassName`. Please notice this  function will return list of elements as more than one element on page can have the same class.

**EDIT**
I was wrong: in order to have `getElementsByClassName` you have to call it on `document.documentElement` instead of `document`

Comment: Hello, thanks for the tips. I guess I have to say that I am new in PS and am still learning the basics, so I apologize if my question is perhaps an easy one. I used the getElementsByClassName:$ie.Document.getElementsByClassName("login-button greenButton").Click(); but this results in the following message: Method invocation failed because [mshtml.HTMLDocumentClass] doesn't contain a method named 'getElementsByClassName'. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: thanks for getting back to me. This is driving me crazy. I now use the command: $ie.document.documentElement.getElementsByClassName('login-button greenButton'). click (). It has the same result: "Method invocation failed because [mshtml.HTMLHtmlElementClass] doesn't contain a method named 'getElementsByClassName'." What am I doing wrong?  I would appreciate if you can help me one more time.

Comment: That's strange. I have tried this code and it worked for me (and indeed did not work for document). On thing I see you have wrong is that you are calling `Click` on a result of `getElementsByClassName` which will not work. This method returns collection of elements so you have to first select one element from it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This problem is killing my brains. Do you have a script available so I can see which elements are present and how I can select one of them? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I just did it in a console against google.com. There's no script I could share. Basically I tried $ie.Document.getElementsByClassName and $ie.Document.documentElement.getElementsByClassName and the latter worked. If you really can't make it work try again with getElementsByTagName only remember to search for button instead of a and remember this will be an array of elements. Hope this helps