# Powershell to press a button in Explorer

Tags: powershell

I have a web page with the following code relevant to the button:

```
<td width=300 align=left>Click here to run the batch tool:</td>        
<td align='left' width=100><input id="Submit1" type="submit" value="Run" onClick='showSts();'/></td>
```

And my attempts to programmatically press it from Powershell using this code:

```
$username='username' $password='password'

$ie = New-Object -ComObject 'internetExplorer.Application'
$ie.Visible= $true
$ie.Navigate("name of Web site")

while ($ie.Busy -eq $true){Start-Sleep -seconds 1;}   

# $usernamefield = $ie.Document.getElementByID('memberemail')
# $usernamefield.value = $username

# $passwordfield = $ie.Document.getElementByID('memberpassword')
# $passwordfield.value = $password

$submitebutton=$ie.Documentelement.getElementByclassname('submit1')  | Select-Object -First

$submitebutton.click()
```

Gives this error:

> You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression. At
>   C:\Users\zkf4bi4\Documents\houdini_click.ps1:15 char:1
>   + $submitebutton=$ie.Documentelement.getElementByclassname('submit1')  | Select-Ob ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull   You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression. At
>   C:\Users\zkf4bi4\Documents\houdini_click.ps1:16 char:1
>   + $submitebutton.click()
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

Any ideas on how to proceed? I'm an experienced developer but am new to Powershell

Answer (score 0):

Well, I can't help but notice that you're calling `GetElementsByClassName` but 'Submit1' is the elements **id**. I suspect the error message is trying to tell you that `$submitebutton` is null. You might find [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18080243/powershell-how-to-press-a-button-on-a-web-page-if-you-dont-know-the-button-id) an almost exact duplicate.